# Django media page not found 404

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to learn to work with Django and i'm making a image app.
Now I managed to upload images to my database, but now I want to retrieve them.

The images are stored in `media/images/`.

Now I made an admin page that looks like this:

[image]

AS you can see the thumbnails don't load.
When You click on one of those thumbnails, I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/june.png
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, media/images/june.png, didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my urls.py of my main thinghy (not the app, wich is called photo):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

Now I'm not sure what I exactly need to do to fix this.
I hope you can help me.
Please be clear ( small steps ) cause I'm not that experienced with django.

Thanks in advance

Oh BTW i'm on Win7

EDIT:

this is what I added to my `settings/py`

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

`MEDIA_URL = '/http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'`

Comment: Are `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` correctly set in your `settings.py`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Comment: This is what I added to my `settings.py`: 
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
`MEDIA_URL = '/http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'`

Comment: Also add urlpatterns to your static files. urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

So right now, your urls.py doesn't have a pattern for /media/images. That pattern probably exists somewhere in your photo app. You need to link the urls for your photo app into your primary urls.py, something like:

```
url(r'^media/', include('photo.urls')),
```

This would tell the app that if it sees a url with media/ it should look for the next thing ('images/') in the photo app.